# Full text search with DB4O

Tags: full-text-search, db4o

In my DB4O database I have an amount of Book objects

```
Book
  +string: Title
  ...
```

When entering a title (string) in my form I would like to suggest existing titles.
Currently I use a simple

```
book.Title.Contains(titlePart)
```

But it would be a nice adition if I could suggest books with titles that match the input title even if it had several, non sequential matching words and give the matches in an order of relevance. In short: have full text search on them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hook Lucene or Lucene.NET to index your text fields. Full text searches will be very fast using Lucene.

Comment: Lucene rocks :) I have read that the DB4O actually uses Lucene internally already. I wonder if there is some way of not having to make my own Lucene index next to the existing one..